# How can I make all of the faces that face XY direction to have same normal axis?

Tags: node-editor, geometry

this is the current object that I'm working on, I want to have all the XY Direction faces to have same normal axis so that I can raycast a grid and move the row on the grid and instances on point it to create a roof. let me know if I need to provide any other information regarding this, thank you[image]

Answer (score 4):

In this case.. (which might be OK for roofing) you can align, say, instance Y to Object Z, strictly about Normal Z:

[image]

The first rotation aligns instance Z to Normal Z, and the second rotation spins instances about their (now good) local Z to the nearest projection onto Object Z.